# JS Me gusaria que enseñara la cancion de la lista

Tags: javascript

Por mas que lo intento sale undefined o [objetc object], soy muy nuevo en esto de la programación, a ver si me podeis echar una manillo, thnks!

```
const lista =[
        {tipo:"Rap"},
        {tipo:"K-Pop"},
        {tipo:"Rock"},
        {tipo:"Música electrónica"},
        {tipo:"Pop"},
        {tipo:"Independiente"},
        {tipo:"Clasica"},
        {tipo:"Country"}
    ]
    
    const reproductor ={
        reproducir: function(id) {
            console.log(`Reproduciendo tipo de musica ${lista[id]}`);
        }
    }
    reproductor.reproducir(lista[2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay un error pequeño de concepto.

Tienes un arreglo (Se identifican por el uso de corchetes en la declaración `[]`) y adentro tienes objetos (Se identifican por el uso de llaves en la declaración `{}`)

Para acceder a un arreglo se hace a través de su índice, como lo haces en `lista[2]`

Para acceder a un objeto se hace a través de su llave, esto es lo que hace falta, tienes que agregar la llave `tipo` en tu `string`

Luego cuando llamas la función estás declarando que recibe un `id` que podría ser un índice o una llave, eso no lo especificas en tu pregunta

Si quisieras acceder por medio de un índice puedes hacerlo así

```
const lista =[
        {tipo:"Rap"},
        {tipo:"K-Pop"},
        {tipo:"Rock"},
        {tipo:"Música electrónica"},
        {tipo:"Pop"},
        {tipo:"Independiente"},
        {tipo:"Clasica"},
        {tipo:"Country"}
    ]
    
    const reproductor ={
        reproducir: function(id) {
            console.log(`Reproduciendo tipo de musica ${lista[id].tipo}`);
        }
    }
    reproductor.reproducir(2);
```

Si quisieras acceder por una llave, podrías hacerlo así

```
const lista =[
        {tipo:"Rap"},
        {tipo:"K-Pop"},
        {tipo:"Rock"},
        {tipo:"Música electrónica"},
        {tipo:"Pop"},
        {tipo:"Independiente"},
        {tipo:"Clasica"},
        {tipo:"Country"}
    ]
    
    const reproductor ={
        reproducir: function(id) {
            console.log(`Reproduciendo tipo de musica ${id}`);
        }
    }
    reproductor.reproducir(lista[3].tipo);
```

Comment: la idea era la primera que has planteado, muchas gracias a ti tambien, crack!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
const lista =[
        {tipo:"Rap"},
        {tipo:"K-Pop"},
        {tipo:"Rock"},
        {tipo:"Música electrónica"},
        {tipo:"Pop"},
        {tipo:"Independiente"},
        {tipo:"Clasica"},
        {tipo:"Country"}
    ]
    
    const reproductor ={
        reproducir: function(id) {
            console.log(`Reproduciendo tipo de musica ${lista[id].tipo}`);
        }
    }
    reproductor.reproducir(0);
```

El problema podría ser que la función(método del objeto reproductor) debería recibir solo la posición del array que le corresponde al tipo de música, y luego en el console.log hacemos `lista[numeroRecibido].tipo`, ya que cada posición del array es un objeto con una propiedad **tipo**, por lo que para acceder a los valores deberíamos acceder al array en la posición X y luego a la propiedad tipo.

Quedando algo así ejemplo:

```
lista[2].tipo
```

Devuelve "Rock".

Comment: Muchas gracias, Luis, estoy aprendiendo y me ha quedado muy claro, gracias crack!

Comment: Me alegro mucho, siempre es bueno poder dar una mano. Si es consideras que la respuesta fue adecuada, favor marcarla como correcta dando click sobre el visto al costado de la respuesta, así no queda la pregunta abierta para siempre, ayudas a subir reputación y además otros usuarios podrían tener la misma duda o similiar y saber que esto puede ayudarles. Muchas gracias, quedo a las órdenes.